# Unable to install Texmaker on Gentoo 3.8.13

Tags: gentoo, latex

I am using Gentoo 3.8.13 x86_64. I am trying to install Texmaker but I am facing some problem.

### emerge -av texmaker

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

```
Calculating dependencies... done!

[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/kpathsea-6.1.0_p20120701  USE="-doc -source -static-libs" 128,853 kB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/dvipsk-5.992_p20120701  USE="-doc -source" 94 kB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/ps2pkm-1.5_p20120701  0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] sys-apps/ed-1.6  85 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-tex/bibtexu-3.71_p20120701  0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-qt/qtxmlpatterns-4.8.4:4  USE="(-aqua) -c++0x -debug -pch" 0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] media-libs/netpbm-10.51.00-r2  USE="jpeg png tiff xml zlib -X -jbig -jpeg2k -rle (-svga)" 1,800 kB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/psutils-1.17-r2  40 kB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/perl-Getopt-Long-2.380.0-r2  0 kB
[ebuild   R    ] dev-libs/libxml2-2.9.1-r1:2  USE="ipv6 python readline -debug -examples -icu* -lzma -static-libs {-test}" PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_2 -python2_5 -python2_6 -python3_1 (-python3_3)" 0 kB
[ebuild   R    ] app-text/poppler-0.22.2-r2:0/35  USE="cairo cxx introspection jpeg lcms png qt4* tiff utils -cjk -curl -debug -doc -jpeg2k" 0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-qt/qtwebkit-4.8.4:4  USE="exceptions gstreamer jit (-aqua) -debug -icu -pch" 0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] app-text/texlive-core-2012-r1  USE="-X -cjk -doc -source -tk -xetex" 998 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-texlive/texlive-documentation-base-2012  USE="-source" 1,441 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-libs/zziplib-0.13.60-r1  USE="sdl -doc -static-libs {-test}" 670 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-tex/luatex-0.70.1-r2  USE="-doc" 9,014 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-texlive/texlive-basic-2012  USE="-doc -source" 5,190 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-texlive/texlive-fontutils-2012  USE="-doc -source" 215 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-texlive/texlive-latex-2012  USE="-doc -source" 889 kB
[ebuild  N     ] dev-texlive/texlive-latexrecommended-2012-r1  USE="-doc -source" 6,631 kB
[ebuild  N     ] virtual/latex-base-1.0  0 kB
[ebuild  N     ] app-office/texmaker-4.0.1  12,760 kB

Total: 22 packages (20 new, 2 reinstalls), Size of downloads: 168,674 kB

!!! Multiple package instances within a single package slot have been pulled
!!! into the dependency graph, resulting in a slot conflict:

dev-libs/libxml2:2
  (dev-libs/libxml2-2.9.1-r1::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    dev-libs/libxml2:2[!icu?] required by (dev-qt/qtwebkit-4.8.4::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)

  (dev-libs/libxml2-2.9.1-r1::gentoo, installed) pulled in by
    dev-libs/libxml2:2/2=[icu] required by (www-client/chromium-28.0.1500.95::gentoo, installed)
    dev-libs/libxml2:=[icu] required by (www-client/chromium-28.0.1500.95::gentoo, installed)
```

It may be possible to solve this problem by using package.mask to prevent one of those packages from being selected. However, it is also possible that conflicting dependencies exist such that they are impossible to satisfy simultaneously.  If such a conflict exists in the dependencies of two different packages, then those packages can not be installed simultaneously. You may want to try a larger value of the `--backtrack` option, such as `--backtrack=30`, in order to see if that will solve this conflict automatically.

For more information, see MASKED PACKAGES section in the emerge man page or refer to the Gentoo Handbook.

Can anyone suggest me, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: [Gentoo forums](http://forums.gentoo.org/) are excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use qtwebkit with icu

for example:

```
echo "dev-qt/qtwebkit isu" >> /etc/portage/package.use
```

I explain why:

```
dev-libs/libxml2:2[!icu?] required by (dev-qt/qtwebkit-4.8.4::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
```

This says that you want to get libxml2 with turned off icu because you want to use qtwebkit with turned off icu. That's default behavior.

```
dev-libs/libxml2:2/2=[icu] required by (www-client/chromium-28.0.1500.95::gentoo, installed)
dev-libs/libxml2:=[icu] required by (www-client/chromium-28.0.1500.95::gentoo, installed)
```

This lines say that you need libxm with turned on icu because you have chromium installed with icu.

So you can't have libxml with and without `icu` in the same time and you turn on `icu` for qtwebkit as you already have libxml with `icu`

Comment: @user44499 good, do you need explanation why does it works?

Comment: yes sure, it would be so nice if you explain it

Comment: @user44499 added in nutshell.